# Queue for best performance and thread safe for multi producers and multi consumers

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have multi producers and multi consumers, what's the best queue in Java to handle this with the best performance time and memory usage?

is it a ConcurrentSkipListSet or ConcurrentLinkedQueue or is there another to consider?

Comment: What actual evidence do you have that the queue you are using has any performance problems?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I mean as time and memory, time because some collections have lock this will delay others producers and consumers.

Comment: and about memory some collections use memory when modify like CopyOnWriteArrayList

Answer (score 1):

The memory usage is determined by where you are creating these large objects in the flow of your code.

if you are creating / holding large amounts in queue, then LinkedBlockingDeque may offer some degree of control. see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html

But if the producers are creating the large objects & very high rate - you will still to deal with it outside the queue.

Comment: thanks for answer, ok I got it about memory but please what about time?

Comment: because some have lock, this lock will delay other threads(producer or consumer)

Comment: what I need it its thread safe queue as modify and get with no time delay because lock or synchronize for other producers and consumers